# Is there any closed-form solution for this MaxMin optimization problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-hulls

Is there any closed-form solution for the following optimization problem?
\begin{align}
&\max_{\mathbf{u}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{u}_M}\min_{i}\mathbf{1}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{u}_i\\
&\text{s.t.}\quad [\mathbf{A}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{A}_M]
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{u}_1\\
\vdots\\
\mathbf{u}_M
\end{bmatrix}
\leq\mathbf{1}_{N\times 1},
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{u}_i$'s are vectors of size $Q\times 1$, $\mathbf{A}_i$'s are matrices of size $N\times Q$ and $\mathbf{1}$ is all-one column vector.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, one can not find a closed form answer if no extra information of $A_1,...,A_M$ is provided.
Let $u_i^*$ be the optimal solition of problem $min\ 1^T u_i,\ s.t.\ A_i u\le 1$. You need to choose from $u_1^*,...,u_M^*$ the maximum, which clearly cannot be done without knowing $A_i,0\le i \le M$.
Moreover, the dual problem of $min\ 1^T u_i,\ s.t.\ A_i u\le 1$ is:
$\begin{array}{lll}
  \max &  & - 1^T \lambda_i\\
  s.t. &  & 1 + A_i^T \lambda_i = 0\\
  &  & \lambda_i \geqslant 0
\end{array}$

Strong duality holds since the original problem is linear. However the problem may be  infeasible, and finding the optimal $\lambda_i^*$ also need to know $A_i$.